# How do I acces javascript database from a html form?

Tags: javascript, html

I just want to acces a database in javascript from a form in the html file and pass it in a javascript function.

So what I realy want to do is take the value that I input in the html and use it in a function that takes some object data and do some simple math.

So the form i want to use looks like this:

```
<form name="mmForm">
       <label for="element1">E1</label>
       <input type="text" id="element1">
       <label for="element2">E2</label>
       <input type="text" id="element2">
       <input type="button" value="Calculate" onclick="procesForm_mm()">
       <div id="resultfield_mm">Result:</div>
   </form>
```

And here is the javascript data i want to acces:

```
var Fe = new Object();
Fe.denumire = "Fier";
Fe.A = 56;
Fe.Z = 26;
Fe.grupa = VIIIB;
Fe.perioada = 4;
```

What I want to do is to acces the `Fe.A = 56;` from the Fe object  while I have the inpun of "Fe" in the html file and then pass it in this function that seems to not work:

```
function procesForm_mm() {
var e1 = document.mmForm.element1.value;

var e2 = document.mmForm.element2.value;

result_mm = e1.A + e2.A;
document.getElementById("resultfield_mm").innerHTML = result_mm;
}
```

I look for some methods to do this trick and help me get on my tracks my first project as a web developer :) so anyone who will help me i will be verry greatefull.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
result_mm = e1.A + e2.A;
```

That part will give you a error since a value does not have properties, what you have to do is this:

```
function procesForm_mm() {
var e1 = document.mmForm.element1.value;

var e2 = document.mmForm.element2.value;

result_mm = parseInt(e1) + parseInt(e2);

document.getElementById("resultfield_mm").innerHTML += result_mm;
}
```

Link http://jsbin.com/ifeluf/1/edit

Comment: did you open the link?? Keep in my that if you click the botton and you've wrote any letter or any textbox is empty will give you NaN

Comment: Yes, but you don't understand.... all i want is when i use the input "Fe" i want my function to extract the Fe.A data from the Fe object witch is 56 as you see... and then use the result_mm method to pass it back to the html.